# slickgrid jquery-ui.sortable module not loaded error in unit-testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, slickgrid

I am running a unit test with angular-slickgrid and it returns me an error as following

```
SlickGrid's 'enableColumnReorder = true' option requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded
```

I have tried installing `jquery-ui` and set the columnReorder to `true` and `false`.

Comment: just checking you are using the 6pac fork: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid  this may fix the issue. if not, be aware that jquery-ui has modules, and you may select various module before you download it from the website. So make sure it's the full version and is included as a reference in your js file.

Comment: @Shehbaz what kind of tests exactly are you running? I don't use `jquery-ui sortable` anywhere in the lib and it's the first time that I've seen this `enableColumnReorder` flag. I suggest you to open an issue on the Angular-Slickgrid, that seem to be a miss from the lib. BTW I'm the creator of Angular-Slickgrid and Ben who replied just earlier is the maintainer of 6pac fork (or I could say, he is 6pac lol).